# Comparing 3 Columns and Deleting duplicates vba

Tags: vba, excel

In this case below I want to compare one column against two columns for duplicates. In the image below column D is compared to both columns B and F and from there I want to be able to delete the duplicates from Column D. I've looked online and I'm not sure how I can do that.

[image]

Comment: Please show at least some effort of trying to solve a problem on your own..

Comment: Thanks @UlliSchmid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will clear duplicate data if the search column is always in column D and the two other ones are in B and F.

Note: This will simply remove the data in the middle column, not actually fill the gaps left.

```
Sub deleteThreeColDupes()

Dim sourceRange As range
Dim colOne As range
Dim colTwo As range
Dim myCell As range
Dim checkCell As range

'Set the search ranges
Set colOne = range("B2", Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp))
Set colTwo = range("F2", Cells(Rows.count, 6).End(xlUp))
Set sourceRange = range("D2", Cells(Rows.count, 4).End(xlUp))

'Compare with the first column. If there is a match, clear the value and exit the loop.
'if no match in first column, compare with the second column.
For Each myCell In sourceRange
    For Each checkCell In colOne
        If myCell.Value = checkCell.Value Then
            myCell.Value = ""
            Exit For
        End If
    Next checkCell
    If myCell.Value <> "" Then
        For Each checkCell In colTwo
            If myCell.Value = checkCell.Value Then
                myCell.Value = ""
                Exit For
            End If
        Next checkCell
    End If
Next myCell

'Clear sets
Set colOne = Nothing
Set colTwo = Nothing
Set sourceRange = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: @LoganReed To be blunt, it is only because I am not familiar with that method. If it works, then that's great! I just haven't used it before.

Comment: [Here you go](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx). It is well worth your time!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help

Answer (score 2):

A bit more efficient version using collections. It iterates columns B and F only once and values can be looked up instantly in resulting collections without iteration.

```
Sub deleteDups()

    ' setup column ranges
    Dim rngB As Range
    Dim rngD As Range
    Dim rngF As Range

    With ActiveSheet
        Set rngB = .Range(.[b2], .[b2].End(xlDown))
        Set rngD = .Range(.[d2], .[d2].End(xlDown))
        Set rngF = .Range(.[f2], .[f2].End(xlDown))
    End With

    ' store columns B and F in collections with value = key
    Dim colB As New Collection
    Dim colF As New Collection

    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In rngB: colB.Add c, c: Next
    For Each c In rngF: colF.Add c, c: Next

    ' quickly check if the value in any of the columns
    For Each c In rngD
        If contains(colB, CStr(c)) Or contains(colF, CStr(c)) Then
            Debug.Print "Duplicate """ & c & """ at address " & c.Address
            ' c.Clear ' clears the duplicate cell
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Function contains(col As Collection, key As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    col.Item key
    contains = (Err.Number = 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Output:

```
Duplicate "cry" at address $D$4
Duplicate "car" at address $D$5
Duplicate "cat" at address $D$6
```

Comment: Thanks for the help